# Check face edge angles on iOS

Tags: ios, arkit, mlmodel, transformation-matrix

I am trying to develop on iOS a system to make sure all angles of a face are being shown. Basically, replicate the same wizard apple does when creating the face ID. I have started today playing around and following some tutorials on ARKit, implementing ARSCNViewDelegate.didUpdate delegate methods and checking ARFaceAnchor.transform, although I am struggling to make sense of the 4x4 matrix.

Is this the right direction? Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Comment: I think that is the right direction.
If you need more help, you should write some code or detail of the problem.